# Bootstrap modal call with javascript, best practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, javascript-objects

First of all, I have 5 modals in layout.

1. Loading
2. Success
3. Error
4. Info
5. Dialogue

And I am calling them like:

```
MessageBox.show('modaltype', 'message');
```

So my actual concern is, my function is sth like:

```
var MessageBox = function($,undefined) {

    return {
        show = function(type,message) {
        }
    }
}(jQuery)
```

Is this the right way to do so? 
Do you suggest sth more efficient?

Comment: I dont know what exactly you tryn' do here but that code looks like something that would throw an error. AFAIK u cannot use `=` in an object literal notation, the thing you need is `:`, also why pass jQuery as a param?

Comment: I wrote it wrong. Actual code is writtin with ':' not '='. I didnt write inner code. Just showing, how I call for showing modals. I already using it. Everything works fine. The thing is I concern with is, I know c# and razor, but I dont know js. For ex, is this function a static class?

Comment: This function is a function. JS is type-less. Even if you use ES6 and have a class syntax it is just a 'workaround'. Technically you can make pseudo-classes but its not the topic of this question. You have a very vague question with no topic I can identify. Be more concrete and precise otherwise I cannot really help you. The js code you have here is not optimal, but to make it optimal we need to know what you want it to do. peace

Answer (score 1):

Here you can check the jquery btn click function call bootstrap modal:

```
$("#buttom id").click(function(event){
$("#modalboxid").modal('show');
});
```

Comment: This code that I share is for ajax callbacks, or backend message handling.  I know how to show/hide modals.